# Check if the given sequences are bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series

$(a)\; 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1,\ldots, n,1,\ldots$

$(b)\; -1, 2, -3, 4, -5, \ldots, (-1)^nn,\ldots$

$(c) \; 2, 1, 4, 3, \ldots, 2n, 2n - 1,\ldots$

$(d) \; 11, 12, 11, 12, \ldots, 11, 12,\ldots$

$(a)$ is bounded below because $1$ is less than or equal to all the following elements in the sequence. No upper bound because a subsequence $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \ldots$ grows indefinitely.

$(b)$ is not bounded below because some of the following elements in the sequence are smaller than $-1.$ No upper bound because $2, 4, 6, 8, 10$ grows indefinitely.

$(c)$ is not bounded below because $2 > 1$. No upper bound.

$(d)$ is bounded both below and above since $11$ is less than or equal to all the next elements and $12$ is greater or equal to all the preceding elements.

Do my answers abide by the appropriate definitions? I am especially interested about $(c)$. My book says it's bounded below, but I don't see how.

Comment: c) It is bounded below by 1. The fact that 1 is not the first term is of no matter.

Comment: "some of the following elements in the sequence are smaller than −1" why would that imply that the sequence isn't bounded below? It isn't bounded below, but that's not the right argument to conclude that.

Comment: Cfr. your answers for (b) and (c): for a sequence to be _bounded below_, the first element doesn't have to be the smallest element.

Comment: I am confused about the definition of bounded below. Can I get an explanation, please.

Comment: That a sequence is bounded below by a number $M$ means that for all members of the sequence $x$, one has $M\leqslant x$. In this case $\mathtt{(c)}$, the sequence is always positive, and all of its members are greater than or equal to $1$, so it is bounded below by $1$, or $0$, or by $-100^{100}$.

Comment: @ Stefan, what's the right argument?

Comment: @ Workaholic, can we say that $(b)$ is not bounded below because for every negative number there's a smaller negative number in the sequence?

Comment: @cat Basically, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sequence with terms $u_n$ (with $n \in \mathbb{N}$) is **bounded above** if there's a number $M$ such that $u_n \le M$ for all $n$. It is **bounded below** if there's a number $m$ such that $u_n \ge m$ for all $n$.

Note that the first term of the sequence doesn't have to be the smallest one for a sequence to be bounded below (what you seem to think). E.g. the harmonic sequence
$$1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4}, \ldots$$
is clearly decreasing and has its largest term as the first term, but it *is bounded below* since all terms are positive; so 0 is a lower bound. Any negative number is a lower bound too. Any number larger than 1 or 1 itself, are upper bounds.

As for your answers; some comments:

- **(a)** 1 is indeed a lower bound, as is any number smaller than 1. You're right about not being bounded above.
- **(b)** The sequence is not bounded below (look at the subsequence of *negative terms*) and not bounded above (look at the subsequence of *positive terms*)
- **(c)** You're right about the upper bound. The sequence is however bounded below, since all terms are larger than or equal to, for example, 0; but also 1 is a correct lower bound.
- **(d)** Indeed bounded below and above, because *all terms* lie between 11 and 12 (included).

Comment: Appreciate your detailed answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Always start with the **definitions**: what does it mean for a sequence to be called _bounded below_? Etc. Good luck!